# Animation repeats after the first animate is finished, how to cancel it?

Tags: jquery, css, animate.css

I'm trying to create a design where you click on a box, it'll slide into another view with more content, and when you click the arrow, it'll return.

The problem is this:

```
        $(boxes).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
            boxes.parent().css({ 
                'height' : '0', 
                'opacity' : '0',
                'overflow' : 'hidden'
            });

            fboxContentCover.css({
             'height' : 'auto',
             'opacity' : '1',
            });

            fboxContentCover.removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
        });

        $(fboxContentCover).one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {

            fboxContentCover.css({ 
                'height' : '0', 
                'opacity' : '0',
                'overflow' : 'hidden'
            });

            $('.fbox').parent().css({
             'height' : 'auto',
             'opacity' : '1',
            });

            $('.fbox').removeClass('fadeOutLeft').addClass('animated fadeInRight');
        });
```

When the first one is done, it goes to the second view successfully, however, when you click back, it'll slide into the first view again, but it'll then flash the second view again and then go back to the first view, again.

How can I stop this from happening?

The code and everything is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNodjO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `.removeClass` doesn't seem to be working properly - the class appears to be reattaching.

Switch from using `.addClass` and `.removeClass` to -> **[`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).**

*It's better for scenarios like yours. Easier to toggle between classes, hence the name*

Comment: Can you edit the codepen and show me what you mean? I changed to:

`fboxContentCover.toggleClass('fadeOutLeft animated bounceInRight');`
and

`boxes.toggleClass('fadeOutLeft animated fadeInRight');`

The second view animation doesn't happen and then going back, the animation stops.

Comment: @kinx I can't do it all for you! But this method should work, good luck!